# How to receive the media id from the Whatsapp Business Cloud API?

Tags: webhooks, whatsapp

I have deployed my webhook and connected my WABA. Once I send an image to this business account. It did not return the media id from the response. Actually, the JSON returned to me like this:

```
{
    "entry": [
        {
            "changes": [
                {
                    "field": "messages",
                    "value": {
                        "contacts": [
                            {
                                "profile": {
                                    "name": "XXXXXXX"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "messages": [
                            {
                                "from": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                                "id": "wamid.aisjdoiajsodiajsodasd\u003d",
                                "timestamp": "1657527108",
                                "type": "image"
                            }
                        ],
                        "metadata": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "id": "124071984791824"
        }
    ],
    "object": "whatsapp_business_account"
}
```

Or should I try the Whatsapp On-premises API? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/on-premises/reference/media/media-id

Comment: It should return `image` property and object with image details, look at the example [payload of image object from webhook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/webhooks/payload-examples#media-messages)

Comment: Yes, I expect it returns the image property to me. But the response doesn't include it.

Comment: It should be there, but if you want more support you have to ask in [facebook support](https://developers.facebook.com/support/), we can't help with this, that is already issue from Facebook meta.

Answer (score 1):

You have to chooose the image_id from the request you receive.

like , `let media_id=req.body.entry[0].changes[0].value.messages[0].image.id;`

you can store this id in DB and use the endpioint where you can get the url for media_id.
Then you can download the image from the URL received and uploaded it anywhere you want.